# printing the book title in the header of a pdf with fop/docbook/xslt

Tags: docbook, xslt

What is the proper string to use in my XSLT to make FOP print the title of the book in the header? I haven't been able to find this anywhere, and any help is appreciated!

**Edit**:

So,

```
<xsl:when test="$sequence = 'even' and $position = 'right'">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="titleabbrev.markup"/> 
      </xsl:when>
```

will print abbreviated section/chapter name. I want to do the same, but for the title of the book.

Comment: just to clarify things: you have a text in docbook format and are now developing the .xsl file to transform it via fop to xyz?

Comment: yes. i've imported the default docbook 5 xslt to my sheet and i'm over riding the defaults. I've seen strings for printing the section or chapter name, but nothing about the book name or title.

Comment: provide that snippet in your question, where you "fop" the header of the page ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<xsl:when test="$sequence = 'even' and $position = 'right'">
 <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::d:book/d:bookinfo/d:title"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:when>
```

The title in this case is nested under `<bookinfo>`. The `d:` label is required. But to do this ensure that you have imported the namespace in the begining of the stylesheet:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
xmlns:d="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
exclude-result-prefixes="d"
version="1.0">
```

After this line you can import the docbook.xsl.

Sample beginning of the docbook with book title:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
<bookinfo>
<title>THIS IS THE TITLE OF THE BOOK</title>
</bookinfo>
...
...
</book>
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but I've long moved on from that project. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintHeaders.html might help. provide the snippet and maybe i can help more.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I came across your question while I was looking for a way to do this.

After some searching I ended up with :

in the `<xsl:template name="header.content">` section:

```
<xsl:when test="$position = 'left'">
   <xsl:value-of select="//d:book/d:title"/>, 
   <xsl:value-of select="//d:book/d:subtitle"/>
</xsl:when>
```

When the title does not fit in the left part of the header you can make the left part wider (100% in this example) by using :

```
<xsl:param name="header.column.widths">1 0 0</xsl:param>
```

somewhere in you config xslt.

Answer (score 0):

A header could be displayed in `<fo:region-before>` what defines the top region of a page.

I can see in your example that you test for 'even'. I gees that you only need this title on even pages. You can do this by defining different page masters (`<fo:simple-page-master master-name="even">`) – look for `<fo:page-sequence-master>` and `<fo:conditional-page-master-reference>` to have odd/even pages. In this page master you define the different regions of the page.